# Parallel Task Run with argument c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parameter-passing

There are a few processes I need to do it parallel but the main concern is, I am passing the arguments to that process
.
The process has two subtasks =>

1. call API 2.Save Response from API in DB `//calling in this function ProcessData(arguments....., shopKey, offSet);`

```
    private void GetMoreData(some arguments) { //calling in 2-3 times Parallel 
        Monitor.Enter(_object);
        long ? maxSearchResults = 0;
        string shopKey = string.Empty;
        long ? offSet = 0;
        long ? pageSize = 200;
        try {
            List < Action > delegates = new List < Action > ();
            if (maxSearchResults != null) {
                double value = double.Parse((maxSearchResults / pageSize).ToString());
                iteratorLength = int.Parse(Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString());
                //some logic to to get no of times we need to call loops
                for (int iterator = 0; iterator < iteratorLength; iterator++) {
                    offSet = offSet + 1;
                    delegates.Add(() = >{
                        ProcessData(arguments....., shopKey, offSet);
                    });
                }
    
            }
        Parallel.Invoke(delegates.ToArray());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        //throw new Exception....
    }
    finally {
        Monitor.Exit(_object);
    }
}
```

In the above example, if we are calling 5 loops,

but when I debug the delegate array I found out like below

GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:5);
GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:5);
GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:5);
GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:5);

delegates should work like this(I want to achieve this) ==>

GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:2);
GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:3);
GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:4);
GetMoreData(arguments....., same_shopKey, offSet:5);

Comment: `new List < Action > ()` - you have some very strange spacing there...

Comment: Have you considered using the [`Partitioner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner), instead of doing the partitioning manually? You could use it like this: `Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, maxSearchResults, pageSize), range => {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop, where you have

```
offset = offset + 1;
```

Make a new variable immediately after this line

```
int x = offset;
```

And pass that new variable `x` in the call to GetMoreData instead of `offset`

```
GetMoreData(..., offset); //no
GetMoreData(..., x);      //yes
```

In a nutshell, all your delegates are looking at the *same* variable, which now has a value 5 because that's what it was after N iterations of the loop.